# In a windows .bat file, how do i find the path to an arbitrary file and then write this to a variable

Tags: file, search, variables, batch-file, return

For example, I will supply a filename and I want the script to search the computer for this file and return the path to a variable.  Psuedo call is:

Set pathToMyFile = SomeSearchFunction(myFileToSearchFor.ext)

Thanks

Comment: Easy to do for a single file.  what do you want to do if there are more than one file found?

Answer (score 2):

`dir /b /s "c:\myFileToSearchFor.ext"` will list every occurance of the file within the C: drive, including the full path information.

The file could exist in multiple locations.

This batch command will set a variable to the last found location:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "c:\myFileToSearchFor.ext"') do set "pathToMyFile=%%~dpF"
```

This batch script will set a variable to the first found location:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "c:\myFileToSearchFor.ext"') do (
  set "pathToMyFile=%%~dpF"
  goto :foundIt
)
:foundIt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function/program that I know of that performs this. If you need efficiency you could write a program that does a fancy tree search through all the directories. I did however find a solution in batch!

`@echo off

for /r "C:\somebasepath" %%i in (*) do (

    if "%%~nxi" EQU "%1" (

                        echo %%i

                break

    )

)`

Passing the file to be found as the first argument to the batch file. But this is very very slow if its in a deep directory.

Comment: you should (1)change `break` to a `goto :eof` or similar (2) use `/i` option of the `if` command.

Comment: also, you might want to parametrize the base path. You might use `for /r "%~dp1" %%a in (*)` and then check with `if /i %%~nxa==%~nx1`